# Smallest circumscribed polygon around regular polygons

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, polygons

> Given a regular $n$-gon $Q$, there are many polygons $P$ that entirely contain $Q$, and such that all $n$ vertices of $Q$ lie on edges of $P$. These circumscribing polygons $P$ have different numbers of edges. What is the smallest number of edges possible for a circumscribing polygon?

In the following pictures, I present the solutions for $n=4,5,6$ for which the smallest circumscribed polygon are triangles, and for $n=7$ for which the smallest circumscribed polygon is a quadrilateral.

[image]

Is the solution of this problem known for general $n$?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Least area or least perimeter? Are you sure your examples are least in either or both senses? Does the symmetry guarantee that?

Comment: Smallest by area, right?

Comment: In your first example solution (triangle circumscribed around the square), what are the side lengths/ angles in the triangle?

Comment: Can I just ask what tool you used to draw your diagrams?

Comment: I suspect that for a regular $n$-gon, the smallest circumscribed polygon  **with the minimum number of sides** will be a $k$-gon, where $$k = \max \left(3, \left\lceil \frac{n}{2}\right\rceil \right)$$

The reason for this guess is that each edge can contain $2$ of the regular $n$-gon's edges.

The proposed formula does work for your four examples, and for a regular octagon, for which a square is the smallest circumscribing polygon.

A pentagon (not regular) should be the smallest circumscribing polygon for a regular $9$-gon.

Edit: thanks Wouter, added "with minimum number of sides"

Comment: @saulspatz could be GeoGebra

Comment: @EthanBolker  Sorry for the confusion, I mean smallest by the number of vertices of the circumscribed polygon.

Comment: If the answer is smallest by area, and the polygon itself is excluded, then I don't think there's a solution, if the original polygon is convex.  Just construct, externally on each edge, a triangle whose base is the edge and whose height is arbitrarily small.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee  Sorry for the confusion, I mean smallest by the number of vertices of the circumscribed polygon.

Comment: @saulspatz  Tikz, and then printscreen

Comment: @J.Bubar yes I think that is the same thing as the smallest number of sides, so it looks to be correct?

Comment: Let me rewrite the question $$\,$$

Given a regular $n$-gon $Q$ with all sides length $1$, there is a set $S = \{P\}$ of polygons $P$ that entirely contain $Q$, and such that all $n$ vertices of $Q$ lie on edges of $P$. The polygons $P$ in $S$ have different numbers of edges. Let $k$ be the minimum number of edges over all polygons $P$ in $S$. What is the $k$-gon that is in the set $S$ with the smallest area? 

$$\,$$

Hopefully that is the question you want to ask. I suspect that $k = \max \left(3, \lceil n/2 \rceil \right)$, but I'm not sure what shape that $k$-gon will have.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Yes it seems correct. And now it looks easy... Thanks!!

Comment: @J.Bubar If you make major changes to the question, it is not enough to bury them in a huge mass of comments. You need to edit the question itself! I have just made an edit, please check it is correct.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Yes it is the same question, but actually I am not looking for the one with the smallest area, only with the smallest number of vertices. Thanks again for your answer!

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee post it as an answer

Comment: In the future, please clarify your question by editing it, rather than in comments. You should even do that now, so that new visitors know what you mean without scrolling through 17 comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a regular $n$-gon $P$, the smallest number of vertices for a circumscribing polygon $Q$ is $$\max \left(\, 3,\, \left\lceil \frac{n}{2}\right\rceil \,\right).$$ Each side of $Q$ can contain at most $2$ vertices of $P$; since all $n$ vertices of $P$ need to lie on the sides of $Q$, $Q$ needs to have at least $\frac n2$ sides.

Comment: I have edited your answer to include the justification for it you gave in the comments, I hope you don't mind. (Feel free to edit again if you don't like my wording.)

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thank you :)